linux command whereis returns the path of a non-executable file
Help me understand the logic, please - from whereis man:
OPTIONS
       -b
           Search for binaries.

But when i use this it returns path to dir:
kl@debian:~$ whereis -b postfix
postfix: /usr/sbin/postfix /usr/lib/postfix /etc/postfix
kl@debian:~$ whereis --version
whereis from util-linux 2.38.1

kl@debian:~$ file /usr/lib/postfix
/usr/lib/postfix: directory
kl@debian:~$ file /etc/postfix
/etc/postfix: directory
kl@debian:~$


whereis isn’t very sophisticated: it matches filenames in a given set of directories. For “binaries”, that includes /etc and /usr/lib, as well as /usr/sbin (and other similar directories), so looking for postfix matches directories in /etc and /usr/lib. You can run whereis -l to see the list of directories it looks at.
